# Testing whether some data is of some type or not in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, static-typing

since Haskell has such expressive type system, is there something supported directly that we can query whether some data is of some type? like in Racket, `(String? "Hi")` (will return `true`)
or like `MyType? somedata -> Bool`

Comment: Why do you need to do this. The only reason I can see is rank 2 polymorphism but its not used much...

Comment: ahh..just want the code looks clean without too much customized little functions flowing around...but obviously, it involves the way how Haskell's type system works. and I am realizing that it is wrong to compare Haskell and Racket in many sense.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
isInt :: Int -> Bool
isInt _ = True

isString :: String -> Bool
isString _ = True

...
```

Comment: Hahaha, this is exactly the answer I had in mind when I saw the question.

Comment: Just for people who don't get the snarkiness of this answer: these functions never return `False`; they will fail to typecheck at compile time instead.

Comment: That first occurred to me as well, but I decided it was better to say why instead of just being snarky. (Also, pedantically, those are partial functions....)

Comment: They are not partial in Haskell.

Comment: @John L: Why? After all, it's not like these functions ever give the wrong answer, so what more could you ask? ;]

Answer (score 12):

In general, strong typing means you don't get into that kind of situation to start with; you always know the type you've been given, *or* you know nothing about it but have a dictionary of supported functions (typeclass instances).  GHC does have `Data.Typeable` for when you're playing dirty tricks with the type system to get generic types, though.

Comment: +1 -- for the (relatively rare) occasions when this sort of thing is *actually* needed, `Data.Typeable` and `Data.Data`, as well as libraries like [`uniplate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate) and such, are the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Essentially, your question doesn't make sense in Haskell.

Haskell knows the type of everything statically -- at compile time. So there is no notion of "testing for a type" -- which would be a dynamic test. In fact, GHC erases all type information, since it is never needed at runtime.

---

The only exceptions to this would be cases where data is represented in a serialized format, such as a string. Then you use *parsing* as the way to test if a value has the correct type. Or, for advanced users, some type information may be required at runtime to resolve certain higher-order generic operations.

Comment: Yes. I admit (nonsense question:). Learned a great lesson from you guys anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check for a type dynamically, then you've done something wrong. This is usually true in most languages with type reconstructors, so functional languages lik Haskell or OCaml or F#.

You have strong type reconstructor and pattern matching, why do you need to ask for a type?

Comment: I dunno. It could be useful in a definition like `foo :: (forall a. a -> Bool) -> (Bool, Bool)`, `foo f = (f 5, f 'b')`. I find it hard to find a suitable `f` other than `id`. Is there another way without something like this to differentiate types? I'm thinking something like `f 5 = True`, `f 'b' = True`, `f _ = False`, possibly with pattern guards instead of just patterns.

Comment: @monadic, because we disallow this, we get so-called "free theorems".  For example, we can find a theorem that any function of type `forall a. a -> Bool` must be constant.  There is a free theorem for every polymorphic type, it's really cool.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers...

You can, if you like, use the `Data.Dynamic` module to work with dynamic types in Haskell.  For example:

```
> let dyns = [ toDyn (5 :: Int), toDyn "hello", toDyn not ]
```

Then you can easily write a test for a specific type using `fromDynamic`:

```
isString :: Dynamic -> Bool
isString dyn = isJust (fromDynamic dyn :: Maybe String)
```

And you can apply that to any `Dynamic` value to determine if it contains a `String`:

```
> map isString dyns
[False,True,False]
```

So if you choose to use dynamic typing using the `Data.Dynamic` module, then yes you can do this.